# Merge multiple PDF files with special order of pages into one PDF

Tags: linux, pdf, command-line-interface

I know that by using gs, or pdfunite utils one can append file1.pdf to file2.pdf in result file.
What I am looking for is the command or util to merge two pdf files with, for example, this order of pages:

`file1_page1 -> file2_page1 -> file1_page2 -> file2_page2 ->` ... etc.

Is it possible in Linux ?

Comment: https://web.mit.edu/ghostscript/www/Use.htm look into command line options, for instance one file per page. Some effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

`cpdf in.pdf in2.pdf -collate -o out.pdf`

Answer (score -1):

Just came across this old question. If still needed the simplest way, if you have a [TeX distribution](https://www.latex-project.org/get), is to use the [pdfages package](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) to create a snippet document as illustrated below which you can then run through, for instance, [latexmk](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) to build the target PDF. See the [pdfpages manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/pdfpages.pdf/0) for the myriad options, in combining and laying out those pages.

1. Create and customise as needed the file `output.tex` in the same directory as your PDF files: `file1.pdf`, `file2.pdf`, ...

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pdfpages}

   \begin{document}
   \includepdf[pages={1}]{file1.pdf}
   \includepdf[pages={1}]{file2.pdf}
   \includepdf[pages={2}]{file1.pdf}
   \includepdf[pages={2}]{file2.pdf}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Build your target document with `latexmk`:

   ```
   latexmk output.tex
   ```

Obviously a TeX distribution is a big beast, and installing it just for that is probably overkill... but it would get the job done :-)